# Why AWS 'input' parameter in 'Application History' of EMR is so big for Spark application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

In `AWS EMR`, if we open `Application History` tab, click on application id of the `YARN applications`, we will see a number of jobs:

[image]

The longest one took `2.6h`. If we click on it we get the following:

[image]

So, here I am really confused why the input is `1.4Tb` since my input dataset size is only `2Gb`. There are reference datasets that the code uses, and they are over `100Gb` of size, stored on `S3`, but in any case even reference datasets combined do not go over `200Gb`. Its a `luigi` `Hail` pipeline that runs on a `Spark EMR` cluster. I am wondering why is that? It matters because the combined `EBS` memory for all the nodes that I use should go over `1.4Tb`, otherwise the cluster stalls as if it does not have enough memory.

Comment: I think, during the process or your code, the spark read the files several times for each action.

Comment: For each 'action'? What is action?

Comment: You can see all the code (very little actually) here: https://github.com/macarthur-lab/hail-elasticsearch-pipelines/blob/master/luigi_pipeline/seqr_loading.py

Comment: Spark "Actions". [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions)

Comment: Yeah, its the 'collect()' one as is seen on the screenshot. The problem is that Hail is built on top of Spark, so I can't really associate directly this 'collect()' with the executed code. How to trace it then to the precise line of code that causes such memory requirements?